# Possible to sort Array in O(n) if 99% of its elements are same?

Tags: arrays, runtime

Asking because of interest;

Assuming the comparison of elements in array takes O(n),
would it be possible to sort the array in O(n) if 99% if the elements are same?

And what if an element in the array appears more than n/2 times?
Still O(n) possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: once you find the element that occurs 99% of the time, you still need to sort the rest of the array, which will contain n/100 elements. We know that a lower bound on the big O of comparison-based sorting algorithms is n log n - so for sorting the remaining n/100 elements, we can't do better than O(n/100 log(n/100)), which is still O(n log n).